# Great papers about actor model

Tags: research

I finally started working on my Master's thesis, and have a problem with literature sources.

My thesis is about distributed system built on top of custom library implementing actor model. But I can't find any good literature that goes deep into this side of distributed software. I've found quite a lot of literature that deals with distributed filesystems, databases, etc... But not a lot of articles/books that focus on object-oriented distributed systems and actor model.

Any recommendations ?